# Sql Query and Double Var Values

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Im having an issue with a certain query,

```
Dim nwLat As Double
Dim Ssql As String

nwLat = nwLatHidden.Value
Ssql = " select * from customer where latitude < " & nwLat 

TFRcount.SelectCommand = Ssql
TFRcount.SelectParameters.Clear()
TFRcount.DataBind()
```

**All it does is refresh the page and does nothing; it should populate a chart.** However when I replace `nwLat` with a value (eg  where latitude = 56) it works perfectly and populates the chart. Any ideas what's wrong with `nwLat`?

EDIT: I switched `nwLat` to long and it works; however it only takes the number up to the decimal and ignores the rest. Any way to fix? (eg as double 56.764746 and long 56)

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong with it.

Comment: What happens when you print Ssql instead of try to execute it? What is the data type of latitude?

Comment: data type of latitude is Number,

Comment: when i switch the nwLat type to long it works however it rounds the number out of a decimal anyway to fix? eg  as double 53.4545 as long turns into 53

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure nwLatHidden has a value?

Try this:

```
nwLat = 56
If NOT string.isnullorempty(nwLatHidden.Value) THEN
nwLat = nwLatHidden.Value
```

Or just put a debugger break in there, run the code to the break, and then mouse-over newLat to see what it's value is.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use mixed mode operations, use

```
Ssql = " select * from customer where latitude < " & cstr(nwLat)
```

Comment: Better yet, don't use string concatenation to create sql queries.  Use a parameterized query, which will eliminate sql injection attacks.